# Mining contracts from peers

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

So I setup my private net and I have multiple computers(peers) connected on this network, but when I deploy a new contract I have to mine it with the machine that created the contract. Shouldn't it be possible for my peers to mine the contract I upload?

***If you need any extra information just ask me***

Comment: What Ethereum client software are the nodes running? Are all the nodes mining? In geth, the `--mine` command-line option starts the node in mining mode. Mining can also be started and stopped from the geth console by `miner.start()` and `miner.stop()` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gethdev.js](https://github.com/amacneil/gethdev/blob/master/gethdev.js) script from [A simple development wrapper for Ethereum's geth](https://github.com/amacneil/gethdev) repo.

> [..] runs a JavaScript file to automatically create the first account,
>   and start and stop mining as needed.

Basically, it starts and stops a miner when there is a transaction from any peer.